# Twitter Bootstrap button dropdown overflow issue when overflow properties are needed

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I'm creating a website where you have a menu on the left that can become super long, so I need to have the `overflow-y: auto` (and I put `overflow-x: visible !important`).
Inside that menu I have a dropdown. But the dropdown is cut off on the right due to the overflow from the left menu. See image:

[image]

How can I make the dropdown appear properly? ie The dropdown shouldn't be cut on the right hand side.

Here is a JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ssL1yydx/41/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are probably looking for something like this http://jsfiddle.net/ssL1yydx/48/

```
#left-menu {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 150px;
    background: #f1f1f1;
}
.btn-group {
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

#main-content{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 150px;
    right: 0;
}

.scroll {
 overflow-y: scroll;  
 max-height: 100%;
}
```

and added this wrapper class to the content that may be too long:

```
<div class="scroll">
```

Comment: This still doesn't let the menu on the left scroll if the content in the menu is high.  http://jsfiddle.net/9dpdbgb5/

Comment: Sorry, misinterpreted the request. Updated the answer to reflect it.

Comment: Apologies for making it unclear. What I meant was that the left menu could become super high (so needs an `overflow: auto`). The dropdown height doesn't matter. I'll update the MP

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the real answer is that you cannot mix `overflow-x:visible;` and `overflow-y:auto;` and that's actually how it's in the spec.

Check this post [CSS overflow-x: visible; and overflow-y: hidden; causing scrollbar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6421966/css-overflow-x-visible-and-overflow-y-hidden-causing-scrollbar-issue/6433475#6433475)

So probably the best and easiest to maintain solution would be to allow your left sidebar enough space to house everything that it needs to, in which this case I've set the width to 200px instead of 150px.

http://jsfiddle.net/t67jg2dh/

Answer (score 0):

You should increase the `z-index` for `#left-menu` and add: `#left-menu .dropdown-menu { height:150px; overflow-y:auto; }`

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Shimyon/ssL1yydx/50/)